# Configuration error: Querying "UUID" failed (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: virtual-machine, macos-mojave

```
Configuration error: Querying "UUID" failed (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND).
Result Code:
E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}
```

I get this error when installing mac  OS  Mojave 10.14.1 on oracle vm virtualbox. How do I solve it?

What steps can I take to resolve the error I encounter while installing macOS Mojave 10.14.1 on Oracle VM VirtualBox?